# Create a login in laravel where credentials are not in the same database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

I need to create a login to an existing database in laravel. The database is kinda weird modeled, yet I cannot change it. I'm quite new to laravel and I cannot figure out how it's done. The login with the normal make::auth seems intuitive, but I don't know how to change the parameters, or maybe you provide me with a completely different solution. How would you implement this login?

The credentials are spread out on two tables:

```
Table: Staff
-----
id
username


Table: Credential
-----
id
password (sha1)
id_staff
```

Comment: Hi, have you found solution ?

Comment: no. I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

In your config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database', // your database
    //     'table' => 'users', // your table
    // ],
 ],
```

Here you can make changes and use another database and table.

If your table is on the same database, you should only need table name here

```
'providers' => [
        'credential' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Credential::class,
        ],
     ],
```

In your LoginController

```
public function userid()
{
   $login = request()->input('login');
   $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'userid'; // you need to customize it to get email from the other table, if your email field is on other table
   request()->merge([$field => $login]);
   return $field;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found this too, but I couln't figure out how to make the configuration with the specifications, I have.

Comment: @moritz 1st to make remote db connection in config/database.php add another connection that will connect to your second DB and use that connection here.

Comment: Both is in the same database.
There are already existing logins, and they're stored in the database as described.
My config/auth.php looks like that, and it doesnt work:

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'model' => App\Staff::class,
            'table' => 'staff',
        ],
```

Comment: @moritz than only change table name.

Comment: I don't under how I change it then. I set up Staff, how to I set the Credentials?

Comment: @moritz edit your question and post the changes you have made, I was actually sleeping and replying from a mobile in my morning I will edit my answer based on your changes or add more details to it. For now if you want to proceed change the users table to yours, if you want to login through some other fields then defaults, edit LoginController, add a login method that will override default login and if required attempt() is depending on how you want to login.

Comment: @moritz I have updated my answer, try it if again you are facing problem or having different scenario let me know.

Comment: @moritz can you let me know, what are the fields you are using for login?

Comment: The field hashed_password in Credentials and the field username in Staff.

Comment: @moritz how this two table are related,any common column?

Comment: Yes. id_staff, I thought I acutally lined it out pretty well in my question.
It now works sort of. Thanks for your help, and I don't really know what was wrong before.

Comment: @moritz if it works for you, you may like to accept this as answer.