# PHP Laravel Auth password from users table, id from another table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've been looking around the internet for a while now and I'm not able to find an answer to my question which is why I am asking it here.

I want to authenticate users to login but this must be done with information from two separate tables.

I am sending to values to my controller: badge and password
I am accessing them with

```
$request->badge (note: This is the account id)
$request->password (note: this is the users password)
```

Previously I have tried the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'badge' => 'required|int',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $account = Account::select('id', 'user_id')->where('id', $request->badge)->first();
    if(!$account)
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['password' => 'Incorrect badge or password!']);
    else
    {
        if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $accounts->user->username, 'password' => $request->password])) 
        {

            return redirect()->route('home');
        }       
        else 
        {
            return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['password' => 'Incorrect badge or password!']);
        }

    }    
}
```

This will log the user in, however when I use Auth::id() it returns the ID of the user and not of the account.

example: $request->badge is filled with 25 (which is the account id), the user id is 1. Auth::id returns 1 instead of my desired 25.

My table looks like the following:

```
users
----
id
username
email
password

accounts
-----
id
user_id
name
```

I have a relationship in accounts and users to link them together

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Accounts::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

I want auth::id to give me 25 instead of 1.

Comment: please share the fields for both tables

Comment: Is it something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982965 ?

Comment: @Joe Added the tables.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu it is like that question, however I don't really understand the method there. I'm not that experienced with making authentications

Comment: check your `config/auth.php`, you will see the table and model specified there, now as your email and password are in different tables, in LoginController, you just need to retrieve that column to check if that is there or not using the common column.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I think I understand that you mean, I could basically make the login system with a db call Account::where('username', $request->username)->withHas etc etc but this doesn't give me the Auth()->id() as account id and not user id, maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mik3NL Have you gone through the discussion in that answer?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I've checked it just now again and I still don't understand how to do it. Aren't you suppose to use the public function store and use Auth::attempt etc to create an authentication? where would I call the function userid if I were to paste that into the logincontroller? I'll edit my answer to try and be more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193380/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-mik3nl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the ID if the correct account it's only a hasOne relationship between the account and the related user.

In your auth config, you need to change the model of the `users` provider to your actual account model:

```
'providers' => [ 
    'users' => [ 
        'driver' => 'eloquent', 
        'model' => App\Models\Account::class, 
    ],
],
```

In the account model we're then adding a global scope which always fetches the password from the related user entry so auth won't have a problem with it:

```
class Account extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'accounts';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('withPassword', function ($builder) {
            $builder
                ->join('users', 'accounts.user_id', 'users.id')
                ->select(DB::raw('accounts.*, users.password'));
        });
    }
}
```

The scope makes sure that the `password` column is always present if you query an account. You can change it up so that the account always includes certain other columns as well, but for now, this should work as expected.

---

In chat, we've been discussing the topic of the advantages of [manual authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users) with either `login` or `loginById` in this scenario. A possible solution would be this:

```
$account = Account::select(
    'accounts.id',
    DB::raw('(SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE accounts.user_id = users.id) AS `password`'))
) 
    ->where('accounts.id', $request->badge)
    ->first();

if ($account) { 
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $account->password)) { 
        Auth::loginUsingId($account->id);

        return redirect()->route('home'); 
    } else { 
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['password' => 'Incorrect badge or password!']); 
    } 
} else { 
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['password' => 'Incorrect badge or password!']); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be on the totally wrong track here, but what you could do is to apply a global scope to the Users model which automatically joins the `accounts` table every time you query for a user.

This join automatically replaces the user_id with the account ID given how joins work but you may have to fiddle around with a [raw select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) to get the values how you want them.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('account', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->join('accounts', 'users.id', ''accounts.user_id');
        });
    }
}
```

To remove the scope from any query you can just use `User::withoutGlobalScope('account')`.

Read more about [usage of global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) here.

Comment: I don't think this will work, one user has multiple accounts. I need to get the specific account that I try to login with, the specific id of the account is sent to the controller.

Comment: Oh, alright. I thought this was a 1:1 relationship. You could try using [different guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards) for this since a user and an account have independent names and passwords.

Comment: I've edited my question, does it make more sense now?